# Software Library to Replicate Logic Analyzer functions with pre-acquired signal data

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

I have data taken from an acquisition system that I want to do some basic logic analyzer type processing on. Specifically I have I2C bus snapshots - SDA and SCL streams taken with a digitial oscilloscope and want to get translated I2C transactions. The oscilloscope gives me a few minutes of continuous bus data at the highest acquisition resolution, the result is about 10 MB per channel of ADC data (2 bytes per sample). I can take care of bit-normalizing and cleaning this data, but am trying to avoid bitbanging the actual protocol analysis.

Existing platforms (e.g. [SUMP](http://www.sump.org/projects/analyzer/)) are about integrating with  logic analyzer platforms and physical acquisition systems and do not expose functions for processing pre-existing data sets.

Preferably a python library, but library for Matlab/Mathematica/R or other high level data processing system will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to take a look at [SigRock](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Main_Page):

- Python
- Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Plug in decoders including [I2C](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Protocol_decoder_HOWTO)
- Works with a variety of hardware or file captures, you may need to do a little work on manipulating your data to a binary signal chain.